# "Заполняется на латинице и кириллице" - как писать правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли выставить такое условие про заполнение полей формы:
"заполняется латинскими буквами или кириллице"? Будет ли это предложение корректным? Предложите, пожалуйста, возможные варианты. Главное условие - поля формы должны заполняться на латинице или кириллице (только буквами, а не цифрами).

Comment: Уточните требование : **на каком языке** нужно заполнять поля формы? Или язык вообще тут ни при чем...

Comment: А слово "латиница" насколько вообще нормативно? Это литературный вариант?

Comment: конечно: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_literature/2623/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, особых ошибок в Вашем варианте не вижу. Может быть можно счесть стилистическим недочётом то, что однородные члены здесь *буквы и кириллица (тоже буквы), но это если придираться даже к столбу.

Я бы сформулировал фразу следующим образом:

**Поля формы заполняются только знаками латинского или кириллического алфавитов**.

Answer (score 1):

Только буквенная запись - латинскими буквами или кириллицей.